# Load parameter from second mysql table when ID equals

Tags: mysql, sql

I have mysql code for fetch all my menus  from MENU table (working properly):

```
$sql = "SELECT id, category_id, menu_name, image_id 
        from menu 
        where restaurant_id = '" . (int) $_SESSION['uid'] . "' && status='1'";
```

But I need data from second table as well. From ICON(table) where is ID value same like in my first table IMAGE_ID value with access to column file_url. 
So I need join this tables.

Something like there:

```
      $sql = "SELECT m.id, m.category_id, m.menu_name, m.image_id 
            FROM menu m 
            INNER JOIN icon i
            ON i.id = m.image_id
            WHERE m.restaurant_id = '" . (int) $_SESSION['uid'] . "' 
            AND  m.status='1'";
```

All working but I still can't acess to value from second table...

Comment: `JOIN`s are your friends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
SELECT m.id, m.category_id, m.menu_name, m.image_id , i.file_url
FROM menu m 
INNER JOIN icon i
ON i.id = m.image_id
WHERE m.restaurant_id = '" . (int) $_SESSION['uid'] . "' 
AND  m.status='1'
```

Comment: Thanks for answer I think your code is best but I don't know why I still can't access to to data from second table...code like this : `<?php echo $crow['image_id']; ?><?php echo $crow['menu_name']; ?>` is working but `<?php echo $crow['file_url']; ?>` not ... Do you have any idea why ?

Comment: because you are not selecting `file_url` in your query :) , look my edit . this let say `file_url` is in table icon , if its in table menu just change the `i` before it to m .

Comment: thanks! I have found myself before...thanks for your help. World is better with peoples like you :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a JOIN statement for that.

http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/

Answer (score 0):

Loop the result and create new mysql query that select something from the table you need:

```
$sql2 = "SELECT (something) FROM (table) WHERE id = ".$row['id'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT id, category_id, menu_name, image_id ,s.file_url
from menu  m
join second_table s on (s.id=m.image_id)
where m.restaurant_id = '" . (int) $_SESSION['uid'] . "' && status='1'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$sql = "SELECT m.id, m.category_id, m.menu_name, m.image_id from menu m inner join icontable ic
    on ic.imgid = m.id
    where m.restaurant_id = '" . (int) $_SESSION['uid'] . "' && m.status='1'";
```